# Execute code on JBoss after start

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jboss, annotations

I need to execute some code after the start of the application server (JBoss).

I googled the annotations `@startup` and `@create` that might prove useful, but in this situation seems impossibile to operate with `EntityManager` or `Hibernate` current session (if using Hibernate).

Is there any chance to perform Hibernate operation immediately after JBoss is started?

Comment: Can refer http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExampleHelloWorldService

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a framework?  If not, you could use a startup servlet.  In your `web.xml`, simply mark the servlet to have a `<load-on-startup>` value and it will run when the webapp is started.  If you want it to load after other servlets, just set the load order.

If you are using a framework, it will have its own methodologies, such as Spring's `InitializingBean` interface.

Comment: Well I'm using Resteasy, but I was looking for a solution "outside" Resteasy in order to easily switch to Jersey or other Java REST Framework in future. I'll try with this kind of servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy a custom JBoss service or just use plain old portable ServletListener in a war.